# Is there a way to get some selected data first & rest data in ascending order through SQL Query

Tags: sql-server

Suppose I have country data in unmannered way (not in sequence) in table tbl. Now I want to show Country  `'United States','Canada' & 'India'` first & rest of the country shown in ascending order.

```
Country

India
China
Brazil
Azerbaijan
Bahamas
United State
Denmark
Canada
```

Now I want this data as :

```
Country

United State        // US,Canada,India should be First 3.
Canada
India
Azerbaijan         // After rest country comes in ascending Order.
Bahamas
Brazil
China
Denmark
```

Any suggestion really appreciate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT Country FROM tbl 
ORDER BY CASE
  WHEN Country='United State' THEN 0
  WHEN Country='Canada' THEN 1
  WHEN Country='India' THEN 2
  ELSE 3
END, Country;
```

Comment: Me like, Except I would use ' instead of " :P

Comment: @NLwino - Good point this query as written will probably complain about invalid column names as double quoted strings are usually interpreted as object identifiers except if `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` is off.

Comment: Thanks its mine answer! & same a NLwino comment ' instead of ".

Answer (score 0):

you could add column FixPosition and then just

```
select * from Country order by FixPosition asc, Name asc
```